# How to parse signature on JavaMail api?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, imap, signature

I want to get the body of a mail without its signature. This code is fetching all text type. How can I extract the text without mail signature?

```
public static void saveParts(Object content) throws  MessagingException {
    try {
        if (content instanceof Multipart) {
            Multipart multi = ((Multipart) content);
            int parts = multi.getCount();
            for (int j = 0; j < parts; ++j) {
                MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multi.getBodyPart(j);
                if (part.getContent() instanceof Multipart) {
                    saveParts(part.getContent());
                } else {
                    if (part.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
                        System.out.println("message content :   " + part.getContent());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch(MessagingException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Signatures are part of the body, and there is no agreed upon standard to separate a signature from content (except maybe `-- <newline>` which has gone out of fashion). You are on your own here and need to define what you consider a signature and the write the code necessary. As it stands, your question is too broad, and maybe a bit opinion-based.

Answer (score 1):

Signature is considered as a part of the mail body content. There is no separate method to fetch the signature alone. You will have to fetch the body of the mail, parse and use it as per your requirement.